# curl/curl.h: No such file or directory (Visual Studio 2022 on Windows)

Tags: c, windows, curl, libcurl, visual-studio-2022

I installed curl with nuget package.

Command that i used to run the command :
`gcc file.c -L C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/lib/libcurl.a -lcurl -o file`

My code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#define DISCORD_WEBHOOK_LINK "link here"
int main(void)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, DISCORD_WEBHOOK_LINK);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"content\":\"Hello, Discord!\"}");


        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What gcc show me :

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` is looking for a file named `curl/curl.h`, but it doesn't know where to look. You need to use the `-I` flag to specify `I`nclude directories to search. This is very likely `-I C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/include`.

You also need to specify additional directories to search for *libraries*, and you need to specify what libraries to search for. The full command should be

```
gcc file.c
-L C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/lib
-I C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/include
-lcurl
-o file
```

Comment: Command :
```gcc file.c -I C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/include -lcurl -o file```
now it show me that he cannot find ```-lcurl```.

Comment: Because you got rid of `-L C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/lib/libcurl.a`. You need to tell gcc (1) where to find the headers, (2) where to find your libraries.

Comment: Command : ```gcc file.c -L C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/lib/libcurl.a -I C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/include -lcurl -o file```
Error i got from gcc : ```c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: Oops. My mistake. `-L` isn't "link this library". `-L` is "add this directory to the library search path". `-L C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/lib`. See my edited answer for the full command.

Comment: Command : ```gcc file.c -L C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/lib -I C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/include -lcurl -o file``` now i get all of that thig when im running this command :

Comment: ```C:\Users\Silme94\AppData\Local\Temp\cc85iBse.o:file.c:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\Silme94\AppData\Local\Temp\cc85iBse.o:file.c:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Silme94\AppData\Local\Temp\cc85iBse.o:file.c:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Silme94\AppData\Local\Temp\cc85iBse.o:file.c:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\Silme94\AppData\Local\Temp\cc85iBse.o:file.c:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'```

Comment: ```C:\Users\Silme94\AppData\Local\Temp\cc85iBse.o:file.c:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: Does the file `C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/lib/libcurl.a` actually exist?

Comment: Acually, yes. Heres all my file in the folder : ```C:/Users/Silme94/Downloads/curl-7.87.0_2-win64-mingw/lib/libcurl.a``` : 


```libbrotlicommon.a\n
libbrotlidec.a\n
libcrypto.a\n
libcurl.a\n
libgsasl.a\n
libnghttp2.a\n
libnghttp3.a\n
libngtcp2.a\n
libngtcp2_crypto_openssl.a\n
libssh2.a\n
libssl.a\n
libz.a\n
libzstd.a\n```